# Cannot import multiple nodes in feeds module using csv files

Tags: feeds

Im trying to import these files into nodes in my drupal 7 site

[image]

i used the no header and i mapped the columns into numbers (0,1,2. ..)

but i end up only getting only 1 node.

The alert says "created 1 node, updated 19 nodes" how come?

[image]

Comment: Have you defined one of your fields as unique in your mapping?

Comment: yes the GUID which i think is default of the feeds module. am i doing it right?

Comment: So what do you map to the GUID? Whatever it is must be in each record, and must be unique.

Comment: feeds module has guid for source and guid for destination. i did not do anything to it. i just leave it as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You file shows 20 rows. From your description, I bet that the GUID has been the same for each import, and you have actually created one node 20 times. (Created once then updated 19 times.) You need to define a unique field in each record, with a corresponding unique field in your node (eg guid). Then feeds will map that field to determine which nodes to create (no nodes with matching unique field) or to update (node has a matching field).

Try using the Title field as unique instead of guid.

Comment: thanks. that fix my problem. but still i dont understand why the GUID is not unique per node?

Comment: The GUID or global unique identifier can be a unique hash, or, for a feed, a unique ID (like part number for an ecommerce site) and must be a part of the record you are importing, and mapped to a corresponding field like field_guid. If it's not in your file to import, then you cannot map it and use it to determine if the node should be added or updated.

Comment: hey mate, @Triskelion. Do you also happen to know how to map a certain comment id to that pid above (i've added another picture above which i will just delete later) Fields mapping doesnt show the pid. What im trying to do is to map threaded comments.

Comment: I have no experience with it, but you should check out the [Feeds Comment Processor](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_comment_processor).